# Rails 3.2 - Uninitialized constant FactoryGirl (Name Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I run command  **rake test:prepare** and display error:

**NameError: uninitialized constant FactoryGirl
/home/dima/myapp/bdsmgalaxy/spec/factories/polls.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/dima/myapp/bdsmgalaxy/config/environment.rb:5:in`'
Tasks: TOP => test:prepare => db:test:prepare => db:abort_if_pending_migrations => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)**

I have **Rails version 3.2**

Its my settings rspec and factories

factories/polls.rb

```
# Read about factories at http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl

FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :poll_item do
    answer "Ruby"
  end

  factory :poll do
    question "What programming language are you using?"
    results_hidden 1
    from_date "2015-06-25 18:13:18"
    to_date "2015-07-25 18:13:18"

    trait :poll_item1 do
      association :poll_item, answer: "C#"
    end

    trait :poll_item2 do
      association :poll_item, answer: "Ruby"
    end

    factory :poll_with_item1, traits: [:poll_item1, :poll_item2]
    factory :poll_with_item2, traits: [:poll_item2]
  end
end
```

gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails',        '2.5.0'
  gem 'factory_girl',       '1.3.3'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0.1'
  gem 'rails3-generators',  '0.17.4'
  gem 'timecop',            '0.3.5'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
end
```

spec_helper.rb:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'authlogic/test_case'
require 'factory_girl_rails'


# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  # == Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  config.mock_with :rspec

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.include Authlogic::TestCase


end
```

application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Bdsmgalaxy
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/workers)
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
    config.time_zone = 'Moscow'
    config.i18n.locale = :ru
    config.i18n.default_locale = :ru
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    config.action_dispatch.default_charset = "utf-8"

    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "flash")
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")

    config.assets.precompile += %w( snow.css w.css w.js swfobject.js hw.css chatroom.js )
    #config.assets.precompile += %w( tinymce/skins/charcoal/skin.min.css tinymce/skins/charcoal/content.min.css )

    config.app_generators do |g|
      g.template_engine :haml
      g.test_framework :rspec, :fixture => true, :views => false
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => 'spec/factories'
    end
  end
end

Squeel.configure do |config|
  config.load_core_extensions :symbol
end
```

Why is displayed error with constant FacroryGirl if i added **require factory_girl_rails**? How me solve this problem?

Thanks for advance.

**EDIT**

**rake test:prepare --trace**:

```
dima@dima-SATELLITE-C660:~/myapp/bdsmgalaxy$ rake test:prepare --trace
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment

Sphinx cannot be found on your system. You may need to configure the following
settings in your config/sphinx.yml file:
  * bin_path
  * searchd_binary_name
  * indexer_binary_name


For more information, read the documentation:
http://pat.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html

rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant FactoryGirl
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.5.2/lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:20:in `const_missing'
/home/dima/myapp/bdsmgalaxy/spec/factories/polls.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/factory_girl-1.3.3/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:314:in `block (2 levels) in find_definitions'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/factory_girl-1.3.3/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:313:in `each'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/factory_girl-1.3.3/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:313:in `block in find_definitions'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/factory_girl-1.3.3/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:308:in `each'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/factory_girl-1.3.3/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:308:in `find_definitions'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/factory_girl_rails-1.0.1/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb:11:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/dima/myapp/bdsmgalaxy/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test:prepare => db:test:prepare => db:abort_if_pending_migrations => environment
```

When i change from **FactoryGirl.define do...** to **Factory.define do...**, display error

**/home/dima/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/factory_girl-1.3.3/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:54:in `define': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)
    from /home/dima/myapp/bdsmgalaxy/spec/factories/polls.rb:3:in`'**

Comment: It's an innocent question, but are you sure you ran the `bundle install` command? Which version the `Gemfile.lock` says that it's installed?

Comment: of course. in gemfile.lock - factory_girl (1.3.3)
    factory_girl_rails (1.0.1)
      factory_girl (~> 1.3)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)

Comment: Did you try require 'factory_girl'? Try adding that line above require 'factory_girl_rails'

Comment: added above require "factory-girls." same error.  when i run test **rspec spec/models/poll_spec.rb** display error: **Warning: Error loading /home/dima/myapp/bdsmgalaxy/app/models/country.rb:
Mysql2::Error: Table 'bdsmgalaxy_test.locations' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `locations`**. Maybe key to unswer is in this issue?

Comment: Thats a completely separate issue - sound like you need to run `rake db:migrate` to setup the database first.

Comment: If you run `rails console`, you can access the `FactoryGirl` constant?

Comment: i run rails c. Same error: **home/dima/myapp/bdsmgalaxy/spec/factories/polls.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant FactoryGirl (NameError)**

Comment: i update quation: added command rake db:test prepare with --trace

Answer (score 1):

I founded solution. I updated version gem factory_girl-rails from 1.1 to 3.0. Old version gem is used old syntax.